# how to disable text message sending in roundcube?

Tags: html-email, roundcube

I am working on a roundcube project and in my project the user is not allowed to send a text email message. He is allowed to send only HTML email messages. Can anyone tell me where can I find a setting/plugin for achieving this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the roundcube config.inc.php, there is a setting variable called 'dont_override'. You have to pass an array of settings to this variable which the user cannot override. To disable the plain text message setting, all you have to do is pass the 'htmleditor' config setting as an array element to this variable, like this..

$rcmail_config['dont_override'] = array('htmleditor');

Answer (score 1):

Log in to ROundcube and go to settings -> composing mail.

You can select an HTML preference there

Comment: I just want to disable the ability for the users to send a text email message. I want the users to only send HTML messages. When I am composing a message, I am getting a select box below the editor for Plain text or HTML, how to disable that?